# Regular expression for search methods private or public not containing comments

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a big pieces of code, so I want to find a regular expression to find all places where my code does not have engineer in the comment before the public or private, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Blah blah
    /// </summary>
    /// engineer: blehbleh
    public class Class1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// engineer: mme
        public Class1()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// get data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="i">i param</param>
        /// <returns>o param</returns>
        public int GetData(int i)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the regular expression should return **public int GetData(int i)** because do not have engineer before it.

Any advice? of course it should support multi line, notepad++ or expresso regex are ok.

Comment: See [`^(?![ \t]*///[ \t]*engineer).*[\r\n]+\s*((?:public|private).*)`](https://regex101.com/r/al5r4z/1).

Comment: A cool trick with skip & fail: https://regex101.com/r/ig0me2/2 . Disclaimer: didn't test it thoroughly ...

Comment: Works as a charm thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?![ \t]*///[ \t]*engineer).*[\r\n]+\s*((?:public|private).*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/al5r4z/1)

**Details**

- `^` - in text editors, start of a line
- `(?![ \t]*///[ \t]*engineer)` - no 0 or more spaces or tabs followed with `///`, 0 or more spaces or tabs and then `engineer` is allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*[\r\n]+` - a line with line ending sequence
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:public|private).*)` - Group 1: either `public` or `private` and then the rest of the line.